# Redirect HTTPS request to HTTP using Java Undertow server?

Tags: java, ssl, https, webserver, undertow

I want to know if it is possible to redirect an HTTPS request to HTTP?

Yes, I know it is not the standard way of doing it, but this is on purpose.

I want to be able to capture an HTTPS request made on my network and redirect it to HTTP.

I have limited understanding of SSL and how redirects work for clients to servers and vice versa, so any insight as to how these things work, and if the scenario I posed is possible would be very helpful.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: @JamesKPolk why not?

Comment: @JamesKPolk I see hotel public wifi networks do it all the time when you try to connect to their wifi network. I just want to take an HTTPS request and redirect to HTTP page.

Comment: Why not? If that were possible it would completely defeat the security of the internet. But specifically no HTTPS client will allow it. What you see in hotel wifi networks is *not* an HTTP redirect.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by James K Polk above:

Why not? If that were possible it would completely defeat the security of the internet. But specifically no HTTPS client will allow it. What you see in hotel wifi networks is not an HTTP redirect. – James K Polk